# popover data-content js listener not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

How can i get a listener woking for buttons inside a **data-content=""**

No problen getting the **a** within the **li** but not the **ul > li > a > data-content > a**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="tabbable indent-1">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a class="bgw" href="#psusel" data-toggle="tab">TAB 1<span style=" font-size:18px;">&#62;&#62;</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-pop="popover" data-toggle="tab" id="make_active" title="bbbb" data-content="<a href='#6ufac' id='listen_here' data-toggle='tab' class='btn btn_primary'>POPOVER B1</a><a href='#3ufac' data-toggle='tab' class='btn btn_primary margin_left'>POPOVER B2</a>">TAB 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


---JS Script----
var make_active = $('#make_active');
var make_li_active = make_active.attr('data-content');
var listen_here = $('#listen_here');    

        make_active.click(function () {
        alert(make_li_active)
        });
        listen_here.click(function () {
        alert("GOT IT")
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so obvious to achieve. Bootstrap plugins has very poor implementation. Particularly tooltip and popover don't trigger any events and has no any methods to reach their content. At least in the official documentation.

But there are some tricks that you can apply to attach events to popover content. Popover stores it's object at the `.data('popover')` of the element. And that object itself has a method to get a popover html object:

```
make_active.popover();
var popoverBox = make_active.data('popover').tip();
```

Unfortunately it is not yet populated with the content that you defined in the `data-content` attribute. But you can attach delegated events on it:

```
popoverBox.on('click', '#listen_here', function(){
 alert('POPOVER B1');
});
```

Profit. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3FzDL/

Comment: If i wanted to make the parent li class"active" when the popupup button is clicked would i simply add:    
    parent('li').addClass('active');

Comment: make_active.parent('li').addClass('active');

Comment: but when the popup dissapears the li is not active anymore.

Comment: Browser follows the anchor link so the tab looses focus. Call `e.stopPropagation();` in the event handler to prevent it http://jsfiddle.net/3FzDL/2/

Comment: I have more than one tab, so using a class makes better sense, but you will see when the link within the popup is clicked the STOPPROPAGATION prevents the tab contents displaying. What i need is the tab contents to display and the tab itslef to be active.... you have almost fixed my problem... i have been playng with .parents etc with no avail. please could you add you final 2 cents to the equastion. thx

Comment: you will note i have js so that when the user clicks away form the popover it goes. i dont see how this willl effect the situation but you will agree its much nicer then having to clcik on the same popover object to get rid of it.

Comment: hey @Razzor The functionality you try to build is quite sophisticated. The stock popover really lacks of the very important features. I used this extended version of popover https://github.com/lecar-red/bootstrapx-clickover Just look at the options that it provides. Everything what you need. And even `onShown` event that you can use to init your popover buttons without using delegated events.

Comment: please let me know what implementations i need to add, switchout etc. to achieve the above. I will look at it on monday but i know there is gonna be a lot to diguest - any pre pointers on which elements i need to draw from?

Comment: i am almost there, i have not used the extra popover js, can you help:

Comment: //POPOVER TABS HIGHLIGHT
var make_active = $('.make_active'),
popoverBox = make_active.data('popover').tip();
popoverBox.on('click', 'a', function(){
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function(e) {
  make_active.parent('li:eq(0)').addClass('active');
   //  e.stopPropagation()
 });
});

Comment: You almost have it! very well done. but there is one glitch. if you start on tab 1, this shows fine, then click tab2 and select any button, then try tab3 etc. then go back to tab 1 and all the tabs are active.http://jsfiddle.net/3FzDL/38/

Comment: Finally http://jsfiddle.net/claustrofob/3FzDL/39/ . Works perfect for me. Also cleaned up and improved the entire the code.

Comment: THANK YOU::$('.make_active').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var popoverBox = $this.data('popover').tip();
    popoverBox.on('click', 'a', function(e){
        $(this).on('shown', function(e) {
             $this.parent('li:eq(0)').addClass('active');
         });
    }); 
});

Comment: an addon would be to make the links on the google chart do the same thing. but i will explore that another day! thanks again.